# AngularJS layout management of header

Tags: angularjs

How can I manage my header layouts in AngularJS? Say I have a master layout as such:

```
<html ng-app>
<header>
    <!-- My header Files -->
</header>
<body>
    <!-- My content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Different pages have different javascript/css files that need to run. How can I manage this with AngularJS `route`? With Laravel blade, layout/templates/partials is really simple. Is there something like that for angular was well?

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familar with Laravel Blade. But you should be able to achieve what you need by simple using the [ng-view](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) directive.

This is [official guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) provides details with how to use $routeProvider combined with ngView

Comment: Did you fix your problem?